# locale-independent way of getting standard windows registry security object

Tags: .net, globalization

Is there a way to get the built-in "Everyone" registry security object in a locale-independent manner?  I want to make a RegistryAccessRule without needing to translate "Everyone" to each language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SecurityIdentifier with the constructor that takes WellknownSidType.WorldSid.  The Domain SID doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor for SecurityIdentifier that takes a WellKnownSidType and use WellKnownSidType.WorldSid.